# When isfile() isdir() is just not enough

Tags: python

`filePath` variable points to non-existent file (yet to be created later).
`directoryPath` variable points to non-existent directory (yet to be created later).

```
filePath="/VolumeA/DiskA/DirectoryA/textFile.txt"
directoryPath="/VolumeB/DiskB/DirectoryB"
```

Since both do not exist we can't use:

```
os.path.isfile()
os.path.isdir()
```

What would be a way to check/verify which variable most likely is pointing to file and which points to directory.

Comment: What do you mean, most likely?

Comment: Just check which one has `.txt` or another file ending.

Comment: Unlike the file name literally contains the string `Directory`, there is no reason to assume that it’s a directory rather than a regular file: there is no way to distinguish regular files from directories by the path string alone.

Comment: Why don't you know before runtime what kind of thing you've put in your variables? What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: @Sputhix It is not about your code to detect, it is about you to decide.

Comment: You can enforce in your code that a pathname is a directory when it ends in `/`.

Comment: Thanks! For my application I have ended up using:    `filepath='/it/is/not/known/if/itis/file/or/directory'; name,ext=os.path.splitext(filepath); if ext: filepath=os.path.dirname(filepath); os.makedirs(filepath);`

Comment: Some dudes keep down-voting my posted question. While the answer keeps receiving up-votes. I don't get the logic. If the question is not worth asking the answer is not worth answering, isn't it?

Comment: Anybody who voted to close this question as "Unclear" obviously doesn't understand the material and should not be voting to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a file can have just about any character in its name, and because a directory can have just about any character in its name, if you have a string and no way to check with the OS, you have no way to tell which it is supposed to be.